# AngularJS ng-model can't get the data from the input field

Tags: php, angularjs

I encounter a problem about AngularJS I can't get the data from the input field.

This is my HTML input field:

```
<input ng-model="dnameform" ng-init="dnameform=user.user_displayname" type="text">
```

And this is how I retrieve data on JavaScript:

```
$scope.dnameform
```

Comment: post your controller as well

Comment: after your "<input ng-model="dnameform" ng-init="dnameform=user.user_displayname" type="text">" do a {{dnameform}}... what do you see ?

Answer (score 0):

In this `ng-init` would result into inappropriate behavior, if `user` object is loaded from `API` service call, the `ng-init` directive fires before than that. So `dnameform` value will be always `undefined`.

Rather I believe you should directly use `user.user_displayname` as in `ng-model` no need of creating new `ng-model` variable.

```
<input ng-model="user.user_displayname" type="text">
```

And wherever you need a value, you can directly use `$scope.user.user_displayname`

---

**OR**

You can do assignment of `dnameform` variable from controller, when user API service call finishes off. Then you're free to use `dnameform` as in `ng-model` on input field without `ng-init`.

```
apiService.getUser().then(function(res){
   $scope.user = res.data
   $scope.dnameform = user.user_displayname;
})
```

Comment: Thank you good sir. I just use the id for it to retrieve the data. I'll try this approach next time Thank you again good sir

Answer (score 0):

use the model as an object and intialise it in the controller like

```
$scope.formData = {dnameform:""}
```

Sometimes we will not get the scope variable value if it is not defined as an object...drawback of angularjs

Comment: How come *its angularjs drawback*? its javascript nature.

Comment: How its become a drawback of javascript? Angular handles the two way data biding right?

Comment: when I said that, I'm saying its nature of javascript hence angularjs behaves the same :)